# OpenCV Error in resize() Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to superimpose a given set of images of the same size (the AT&T facial images database). I have written the code to do so, which works as follows:

1. I have assigned the location of the images (for starting I am
   considering only 4 images).
2. imstack is used to read one image (as a base image) over which the
   layover (superimposition) will take place.
3. A for loop is run that goes through all the images and adds them to
   the base image (imstack). This adding is done by using the
   addWeighted() function with the parameters as the current image (im)
   and the base image (imstack) with the alpha values as 0.5
   respectively.
4. After the loop has run till its completion (all the images are
   superimposed on the base image) I tried to print the updated imstack
   as 'compiledimg' by using the imshow().
5. Further I added the option to save the 'compiledimg' file by
   pressing 's'.

**Error:**

imstack=cv2.resize(imstack,(97,113))
cv2.error: /build/opencv-RI6cfE/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:1834: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0 in function resize

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import os

fnames =['~/Downloads/1.pgm','~/Downloads/2.pgm','~/Downloads/3.pgm']

imstack=cv2.imread('~/Downloads/4.pgm')

imstack=cv2.resize(imstack,(97,113))

for path in fnames:
  im=cv2.imread(os.path.expanduser(path))

  imstack=cv2.addWeighted(imstack,0.5,im,0.5,0)

  imstack=cv2.resize(imstack,(97,113))

cv2.imshow('compiledimg.jpg',imstack)

k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF

if k == 27:         
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

elif k == ord('s'): 
  cv2.imwrite('compiledimg.jpg',imstack)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: make sure the image is loaded, after the imread function, print shape to see if the image was loaded correctly (it should print (height, width, channels), if you see 0,0 then it is not loaded). Verify you wrote the filepath correctly, and I would suggest to use, a full path with no abbreviations

Comment: Note that you are using os.path.expanduser in second imread but not in first imread

Comment: @Dimitrii that is because I am using the imstack as a base image over which the other images will overlay. Where as in the second imread where I am reading the image 'im' is going to change for each path that is why there is a os.path.expanduser which will change after each iteration.

Comment: @appi55 Thank you that was the issue. I ran print for the first imstack image and it said it was a null attribute. I made some changed to the path and you mentioned and it helped me fix this error. 
Although now I am facing another error so wish me luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of this error. 
Mainly I made two mistakes:

1. Corrected the way I did paths. Read more stuff and finally got it done.
2. I had to check weather the reading input as imstack was being read at all or not, and since previously my path was wrong so it was being fed as NULL hence the error.

Where 4.pgm is the base image and 2.pgm is the image that I will use a test so I did not what to include it in the path of the images that will be overlayed.

The improvised part of the code is as follows:

```
path='test/'

#Appends all the absolute paths in the list image_paths 
image_paths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if not f.endswith('2.pgm')]

#initializing a base_image over which other images will be superimposed
base_image=cv2.imread('4.pgm')

#resizing the base image so it matches the size of the database pics (113(rows),97(columns))
base_image=cv2.resize(base_image,(97,113))

#cv2.imshow('lol',base_image) //for testing purposes
```